# Changing employers during the application

Tags: tourist-visas, applications, application-status, proof-of-employment

I have a question regarding the past employer section and would really thankful if anyone could provide me with an answer.

Currently I am employed at a company A but I am starting a new job on the 1st of January at company B.

Do I need to list company A as past employer considering that my application might be reviewed after Jan 1st when my current employer will already be a past employer.

Unfortunately, I am not able to find any information on this matter..

Comment: Hi, which country's tourist visa you are applying for?